# CirclePagerIndicator over ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I'm making an image slideshow using `ViewPagerIndicator` to show the current position in the slideshow. All works fine when I use it as described in the documentation, however I want the `ViewPager` and the `CirlePagerIndicator` enclosed in a layout for which I provide a border. When I try to do so, only the `ViewPager` is on top and I'm not able to see the `CirclePagerIndicator`.

*So how do I get the `CirclePagerIndicator` on top of `ViewPager`?*

Here's my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_margin="3dp"
         android:background="@drawable/stroke"
         android:layout_weight="0.33">

         <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

        <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/titles"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" /> 

   </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
     .
     .
     .other stuffs
```

I know that items inside `RelativeLayout` are placed in a z-order stack.So I've put `CirclePagerIndicator` below so that it shows up on the top. Also, by doing this will I be able to capture the touch event on the `ViewPager`?

This is how I'm adding images to `ViewPager`

```
 @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) 
        {
            Context context = LoginActivity.this;
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

            imageView.setImageResource(myImages[position]);
            imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
            return imageView;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this on top if you want it to be on top. With attribute `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`

and add your `ViewPager` below `CirclePageIndicator`

```
<com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/titles"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" // Here this will put it on top
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" /> 

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/titles" // Here this will put it below CirclePageIndicator
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Comment: 01-18 14:33:43.228: E/AndroidRuntime(16095): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator cannot be cast to android.support.v4.view.ViewPager             I get this

Comment: This error you got because you are passing the `id` of `CirclePageIndicator` but casting it into `ViewPager`. Look at the line `findViewById` in your code. Can you share what has been written there?

Comment: CirclePageIndicator titleIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.titles);   viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

Comment: And change this `android:layout_below="@+id/titles"` with `android:layout_below="@id/titles"` in your layout.

Comment: That was my mistake i put it wrong i have edited it though. just check after changing it.

Comment: I've written as `android:layout_below="@id/titles"` only. Now the interesting thing is when I swap the position of `ViewPager` and `CirclePagerIndicator` I don't get that error, but also no Circle Indicators.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45530/discussion-between-user3110424-and-psygik)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, this is the how..

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_margin="3dp"
         android:background="@drawable/stroke"
         android:layout_weight="0.33">

         <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

        <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/titles"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" //this line
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" /> 
   </RelativeLayout>
```